# Errors in payement method after migratting website to another server (joomla)

Tags: migration, joomla2.5, virtuemart

Please help me with this error. I re-checked all the URLs and access rights but the error persist (this happens only after the migration of the website to another server)

See screenshot please : http://data.imagup.com/10/1175591931.png

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need to see the code in checkout.sips_cc_form.php to be sure, but without looking I would guess that the new server is using a different version of PHP.

Comment: The first and second errors indicate that the array you are looking at is empty - you did not get any results. Since this appears to be a written for Joomla 1.5 and VM 1.1, I would guess that the new server is on PHP 5.3.x and the old one is 5.2.x or older.

Comment: the two server have 5.3.x as PHP version. Yes Joomla 1.5 and VM 1.1. Is it possible to upgrade the website without crashing it ?

Comment: How did you move the site?